# Adding new user to multiple O365 Distribution Lists

Tags: powershell

We currently have a load of Distribution Lists and when a new user starts with the business, depending on which area they work for they get added to a different DL. Now I'm not in charge of our tenant so using Dynamic Groups isn't an option for now so I'm having to get creative with our New User Tool.

So I can get this to work manually just using it the once but when I try and get this to work from data within a cell in a csv it's failing to separate the distribution lists out.

So this is the manual bit I can get to work just running through Powershell...

```
$dls = "DL1","DL2"
$dls | Foreach-Object {Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_ -Member "UserEmail"}
```

So that works fine but when trying to run the below I get an error...

```
Import-csv 'ImportPath' | foreach-object {
$DLs = $_.DistributionLists
$DLs | Foreach-Object {Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_ -Member UserEmail}
}
```

I get this error for this one so I presume Powershell doesn't like the way I've foreached twice.

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Add-DistributionGroupMember
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

I've also done some googling and pieced together this from another solution to a similar issue I found [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98f13482-d7b2-43a3-a1c3-a4ff536c5254/how-to-add-multiple-members-in-multiple-distribution-groups-by-using-powershell-script-office-365?forum=onlineservicesexchange)

```
$DGs = Import-Csv "ImportPath"
$DGs | foreach {
[string]$Group = $_.Group
$Groups = $Group.replace(" ","") -split ","
IF ($Groups) { 
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Groups -Member "UserEmail"
}
}
}
```

and that comes back with an error

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'DL1 DL2' couldn't
be found on '*.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-DistributionGroupMember], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=*,RequestId=*,TimeStamp=17/09/2019 14:37:41] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException]*,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.AddDistributionGroupMember
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Sorry for the essay and my rubbish attempts at piecing together a powershell script, have been attempting to make a few tweaks here and there but not having any joy. Just wondering if there is a way to have Powershell treat the data as plain text like in the manual variable in the first example that works. Data in the csv just has one column with a column header & then the two DLs seperated by a comma (have tried inputting the data surrounding each DL with " & ' and even just the names but no luck any way I try it).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below function as a solution to your problem.

```
Function AddTo-DistributionGroups {
    Param(
    [String]$User,
    [String]$BusinessUnit,
    [String]$CSVLocation
    )
    $Data = Import-CSV -Path $CSVLocation
    Foreach ($Line in $Data){
        If($Line.BusinessUnit -eq $BusinessUnit){
            Foreach($DG in $line.DGs.split(";")){
                Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DG -Member $User
                Write-Host Added $User to $DG
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would format your CSV in the following way:

```
BusinessUnit,DGs
NorthWest,DG1;DG2;DG3
SouthWest,DG2;DG5
Europe,DG7;DG8;DG9
```

This allows you to populate the 1st cell with the business unit name, the second cell with distribution groups separated by semi-colon. Please ensure the 2 top cells in Excel contain "BusinessUnit" & "DGs" respectively.

To use the function:

```
AddTo-DistributionGroups -User <User Email> -BusinessUnit <BusinessUnit Name> -CSVLocation <Location of CSV>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use text files, I need to be able to do it from a cell in a csv. We have multiple different business units in our company & each different business unit gets added to a different set of distribution lists so it wouldn't be a set text file that I could use, there would have to be hundreds with different DLs in each.

Comment: Answer has been modified to use CSV as per request, apologies I misread the end of you initial question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously not clarifying how we're currently creating new users properly. 

So currently we have a csv with all the details that the new user will have against his profile. So a csv with seperate columns Name, Samaccountname, UPN, Office, etc. Now when the new user starts with the business they go into a business unit, South West for example (we have hundreds of different business units). Now anyone new that starts with the company, depending on their business unit currently gets manually added into 4 or 5 different distribution lists and these are different for every...

Comment: business unit. What I want to do is have 2 cells next to each other in excel. First cell will be which business unit they will be part of and the second cell is a comma separated list of DLs which will auto populate dependent on which business unit you select. I can get it to work when running manually in my original post but when powershell is getting the comma separated list of DLs from the csv it's failing.

Comment: Updated again taking the additional information into consideration. I have also have taken a slightly different approach but this should work as you have intended.